# Why is dispatch property undefined for a connected wrapped component within a connected Higher Order Component when using react-redux with typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am new user struggling with the following issue. I have a Higher Order Component (Hoc) that injects properties to a wrapped component. The HoC itself returns a React.ComponentClass that is connected to the redux store with map and dispatch properties.

I am trying to use the HoC with a component that is also connected to the redux store. Using console log output statements I can see that all properties within the wrapped component are initialised aside from the dispatch properties, which are undefined. I do not understand why the dispatch properties are undefined in the wrapped component????

I am using react-redux 7.1 and deriving map and dispatch properties with the `ConnectedProps` react-redux type.

**Higher Order Component**

```js
import cuid from 'cuid';
import React, { Component, ComponentType } from 'react';

import { ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { ApiErrorDialog } from './ApiErrorDialog';
import { ApiErrorListenerComponentProps } from './types';
import { connector } from './reduxConnect';

/**
 * Type declarations
 */
type HocState = {
  componentId: string;
};

type ReduxProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export const withReduxErrorListener = <
  BaseProps extends ApiErrorListenerComponentProps
>(
  BaseComponent: ComponentType<BaseProps>,
) => {
  /**
   * Type declarations
   */
  type HocProps = BaseProps & ReduxProps & RouteComponentProps;
  type HocPropsExcludingBaseProps = Exclude<HocProps, BaseProps>;

  console.log(
    `withReduxErrorListener BaseProps => ${JSON.stringify(
      BaseComponent.displayName,
    )}`,
  );

  class ApiErrorListener extends Component<HocProps, HocState> {
    static displayName = `withReduxErrorListener(${BaseComponent.name})`;
    static readonly WrappedComponent = BaseComponent;
    /**
     * Some source code .....
     */


    render(): JSX.Element {
      const { ...restProps } = this.props;
      console.log('hoc render()');

      if (this.props.error.length > 0) {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            /*{display custom error component here}*/
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      } else {
        // display base component
        return (
          <BaseComponent componentId={this.state.componentId} {...restProps} />
        );
      }
    }
  }

  const ConnectedHoc = connector(ApiErrorListener as any);
  const RoutedConnectedHoc = withRouter(ConnectedHoc as any);
  return RoutedConnectedHoc;
};
```

**Wrapped Component**

```js
type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  courses: courseModels.Course[];
};

/**
 * Redux dispatch and state mappings
 */
const dispatchProps = {
  fetchCourses: apiCourseAction.request,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.courses.isLoadingCourses,
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses),
});

const connector = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  dispatchProps,
);

type ReduxProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

/**
 * Component property type definitions
 */
type Props = ReduxProps & ApiErrorListenerComponentProps; // &RouteComponentProps;

/**
 * CourseList component
 */
const CourseListBase = ({
  courses = [],
  componentId,
  fetchCourses,
  isLoading,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  // dispatch fetch course action on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('My properties are:=> ');
    console.log(`courses :: ${JSON.stringify(courses)}`);
    console.log(`componentId :: ${componentId}`);
    console.log(`fetchCourses :: ${JSON.stringify(fetchCourses)}`);

    console.log('COURSELIST FETCHING COURSES');
    fetchCourses(requestFactories.getCourses(componentId));
  }, [fetchCourses]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Exports
 */

const ConnectedCourseList = connector(withReduxErrorListener(CourseListBase));
export default ConnectedCourseList;
```

**Updated 26/11/2019**
In response to comment, I have created a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-cuq6i). So far, the issue has not manifested in the codesandbox, so will investigate further in my original codebase. Being a new react-redux user, any feedback concerning if I am correctly connecting to the redux store in the higher order component and base component of the codesandbox code, would be appreciated.

I am also experiencing a separate issue, detailed in readme file of code sandbox, for which I will raise a separate question.

Comment: Please create a *minimal* (but complete) reproduction example. In the course of doing so you will likely solve your own problem, and if you don't it will make it significantly easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks @jared-smith. I have created a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-nested-connected-hoc-example-cuq6i). Think this is working but have another issue as detailed in readme file of code sandbox. Keeping this question open for now until more certain and will raise a separate question for other issue.

Comment: PS, As a new react-redux user, any feedback concerning if I am correctly connecting to the redux store in the higher order component and base component would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. The issue was caused by incorrectly connecting the HoC to redux store, i.e. component was casted to any. This issue was solved in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088446/experiencing-compile-error-with-a-higher-order-components-mapstate-function-tha).

Refactored the HoC to follow the [nested HOC pattern](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#--nested-hoc---wrapping-a-component-injecting-props-and-connecting-to-redux-) in the [react-redux-typescript-guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide)

Thanks to the author of the guide for his time and patience in identifying a solution. Thanks to the downvoter for suggesting a minimal reproduction of the problem.

A codesandbox model can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/witherrorlistener-and-withid-hoc-components-the-version-that-compiles-207sg)